# IS the new SharePoint 2013 Cumulative updates include all previous Cumulative updates and Service packs?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

Hi the new SharePoint 2013 Cumulative updates include all previous Cumulative updates and Service packs because in my farm when I join the new server I am facing issues, when I install March 12, 2019, cumulative update for SharePoint Enterprise Server 2013 (KB4462219) and run the Configuration wizard it showing missing locally below service pack 1.

Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552)

Comment: Did you install SharePoint 2013 RTM or SharePoint 2013 SP1? Service Pack 1 is always needed and provided with the later ISO. Install SP1 and rerun the wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the KB of the CU to check if it includes all previous Cumulative updates and security updates like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464514/april-9-2019-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-enterprise-server-2013-k).

If it contains, you will see like the below:
[image]

But, if you install a CU after SP1 for SharePoint 2013, you need to make sure you have installed SP1 which is a prerequisites.